# Replace Values in R - Error Received

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataframe, titled `gen`, which is a data frame made up of A's, C's, G's, T's, and 0's. I would like to replace the A with a 1, the C with a 2, the G with a 3, and the T with a 4. When I try using the code `gen1[gen1 == "A"] = 1`, I get the error message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "1") :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

The resulting data frame has all of the A's replaced, but there are NA's instead of 1's.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: See what I said about factors in your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768599/replacing-values-in-r-error-received.

Comment: can you show `str(gen1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### solution:

You can use coerce your column factors to integer using `as.integer`:

Using `sapply`:

```
sapply(gen1,as.integer)
```

and `colwise` from `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
colwise(as.integer)(gen1)
```

For example, I generate first a data.frame of A,B,C and D:

```
 set.seed(1)
gen1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:4], 4 * 5, rep = TRUE), ncol = 4))
##   V1 V2 V3 V4
## 1  B  D  A  B
## 2  B  D  A  C
## 3  C  C  C  D
## 4  D  C  B  B
## 5  A  A  D  D
library(plyr)
colwise(as.integer)(gen1)
##   V1 V2 V3 V4
## 1  2  3  1  1
## 2  2  3  1  2
## 3  3  2  3  3
## 4  4  2  2  1
## 5  1  1  4  3
sapply(gen1, as.integer)
##      V1 V2 V3 V4
## [1,]  2  3  1  1
## [2,]  2  3  1  2
## [3,]  3  2  3  3
## [4,]  4  2  2  1
## [5,]  1  1  4  3
```

#### Why do you get the warning?

The warning messages is explicit , `invalid factor level, NAs generated`.

You get the error because you try to modify a factor value with a value that don't belong to levels set, So it will replaced by NA. I will reproduce the error :

```
h <- data.frame(xx = factor(c("A","B")) )
h[h == "A"] <- "C"   ## C don't belong to levels of xx 
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = "C") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting argument `stringAsFactors = False` while making the Data Frame. By default it is true.

Example Code:

```
d <- data.frame(a=c('A','C','G','T','0'),b=c('C','A','G','A','0'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> d
  a b
1 A C
2 C A
3 G G
4 T A
5 0 0
> d[d=='A']<- '1'
> d
  a b
1 1 C
2 C 1
3 G G
4 T 1
5 0 0
```